# Can't open lib 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0' Python3, Linux ubuntu

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to connect to an MSSQL server with python console to test connection and get the tables of a database, here is my code

```
>>>from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>>engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://username:password@host:port/databasename?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+10.0")
>>> connection = engine.connect()
```

it returns this error to me

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

i've installed pyodbc. 
i tried changing the Driver to 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0' and even 'SQL Server', still returns same error.

Please what do i do? don't seem to know what I haven't done or done wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

so i made some more research and i discovered i wasn't using the right driver, and my pyodbc did not have that driver. probably because i had installed both

here is how i checked the drivers available to me.

```
>>>import pyodbc
>>> for driver in pyodbc.drivers():
...     print(driver)
```

and the out put was

```
ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
```

so i simply changed the code to

```
>>>engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://username:password@host:port/databasename?driver= ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server")
>>> connection = engine.connect()
```

and it went through.